# styled-components - create class method?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components, css-in-js

I need a way to create classes without `styled` nor `css` method.

Lets assume proper style system with components having only basic styles, but *not* positioning, margin etc.

e.g.

```
const Root = styled.div`/* Some styles */`

export const MyComponent = ({className}) => <Root className={className} />
```

So this is easy, I attach private styles for component and I allow it to receive and apply class from parent.

If I have "classic" css, I would use it like this

```
import styles from 'some-styles.module.css';

...

<MyComponent className={styles.someStyle} />
```

Which will work as expected.

**Here is the problem:**

How do I create a class with `styled-components` only? It was working with `Glamorous` once, but SC (and Emotion) is *not* returning class name from `css`.

I can't use separate css files just to allow this styling, which should be common use case (parent setting size of children)

**Edit & solution in Emotion**

I figured out that Emotion adds extra property `css` which is available for every jsx element.
It can be used to native `<div>`, styled `<Div>` or custom React component `<MyComponent`.
Babel is changing `css` attribute with `css({...})` to className during compilation.
If `<MyComponent>` only accepts prop `className` it will receive it from parent via `css` prop.

Comment: Not sure if I got it right, but you want to use styled components to generate only the className and not a component?

Comment: `styled-components` make `className` an implementation detail. You should not work with `className`s directly when using `styled-components`. This question is XY problem.

Comment: @Vencovsky, yes, I use both.

Comment: @marzelin I understand, however I still belive I should be able to somehow pass styles from parent to child. How to achieve this other way? I can try passing `css`, not sure if it will work though.

Is it implementation detail... I dont think I agree. Yes, SC use them under the hood, but this is still a web api standard, so it should have flexible api to work with it (and it does, somehow), I just need a way to get access for its creation. Emotion has `<Classnames` util for that

Answer (score 0):

> I still belive I should be able to somehow pass styles from parent to child.

There is a way to do that, but no exactly the way you want to do.

In react js (you can't do this in React Native yet), you can pass the child component inside the parent style and it will add the style in the child when it's wrapped by the parent.

e.g.

```
const ParentComponent = styled.div`
    ${ChildComponent} {
         /* Child css*/
    }
`
```

Sorry if formatting is bad, I'm on mobile

Comment: Thanks for answer but it's still not the case. Your case assumes we are inside one "React Component". I'm talking about composition between components. I dont have access from parent to styled instance.